# Recommended ADSL2 + Wifi N setup - all in one or separate wireless router?

Tags: internet, wireless-networking, adsl

Firstly - what is a great brand people use for ADSL - I seem to have endless troubles with them.

My latest is a Belkin, which seems to have trouble allowing wireless N devices on until a reboot is performed (of the modem).

Should I get a simpler ADSL2+ only modem and hook it up to a quality wireless router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. Get the modem and router separately. If you get one of [these routers](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices_802.11n), you can upgrade the firmware to [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT).

Comment: I ended up with a LinkSys ADSL modem, and bought an airport extreme from apple which does all the routing. Everything seems so much smoother, thanks for advice.